# How to activate selected text replacement when typing new text?

Tags: selection, netbeans-7, highlighting, replace

Usually when you selected a text area if you write some text using the keyboard, the selected text will be deleted and you will start writing in its place (work this way in **Netbeans 7.2**).

For some reasons in **Netbeans 7.3** this will not work any more and you have to use `Del` or `Backspace` to remove the highlighted text or it will stay and you will start writing after it, and this is a bit annoying imo. 
Using "Paste" on the selected area will correctly replace the old text as usual.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug.
E.g. for python it is still open: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209498